# GDAL Build Curl Error

Tags: gdal, build

I'm building GDAL 2.4.1 with the following config options

> ./configure --with-libtiff=internal --with-geotiff=internal --with-jpeg=internal --with-gif=internal --with-openjpeg --with-opencl=yes --with-opencl-include=/usr/local/cuda/include --with-opencl-lib='-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lOpenCL' --with-python=yes --with-libkml=yes --with-png=yes --with-sqlite3=yes --with-spatialite=yes --with-python=yes --with-geos=yes --with-curl=/usr/bin/curl-config

and I'm getting the following error during build

```
/home/ruggedroutes/Sources/gdal-2.3.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `curl_multi_info_read'
/home/ruggedroutes/Sources/gdal-2.3.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `curl_slist_append'
/home/ruggedroutes/Sources/gdal-2.3.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `curl_multi_add_handle'
/home/ruggedroutes/Sources/gdal-2.3.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
/home/ruggedroutes/Sources/gdal-2.3.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `curl_multi_perform'
/home/ruggedroutes/Sources/gdal-2.3.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `curl_multi_cleanup'
/home/ruggedroutes/Sources/gdal-2.3.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
/home/ruggedroutes/Sources/gdal-2.3.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
/home/ruggedroutes/Sources/gdal-2.3.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `curl_multi_remove_handle'
/home/ruggedroutes/Sources/gdal-2.3.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/home/ruggedroutes/Sources/gdal-2.3.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `curl_version'
/home/ruggedroutes/Sources/gdal-2.3.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `curl_easy_getinfo'
/home/ruggedroutes/Sources/gdal-2.3.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `curl_slist_free_all'
/home/ruggedroutes/Sources/gdal-2.3.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `curl_multi_init'
/home/ruggedroutes/Sources/gdal-2.3.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `curl_multi_fdset'
/home/ruggedroutes/Sources/gdal-2.3.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `curl_version_info'
/home/ruggedroutes/Sources/gdal-2.3.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `curl_multi_wait'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [gdalinfo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ruggedroutes/Sources/gdal-2.3.3/apps'
make: *** [apps-target] Error 2
```

I'm really not sure what to do about this.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to solve my issue. I configured with `--with-curl=no`
How you would configure it with curl should you need it.. I have no idea.
I did install curl-devel prior to trying this as well.